# Opening popup without scrolling bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liferay, liferay-aui

I'm working with js, jQuery library, in a Liferay Portal webpage and when I popup a content the content information protrudes the window.

What I should do if I want a scrollbar to set the content inside the popup?¿

Here is my code...

```
function showpopup(id) {
    AUI().ready('aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe','liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
        var url = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
        url.setPortletId("56"); //  "Web Content Display" portlet ID
        url.setWindowState('pop_up');
        url.setParameter("_56_groupId", Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getScopeGroupIdOrLiveGroupId()); 
        url.setParameter("_56_articleId", id); // webcontent ID

        window.myDialog = new A.Dialog(
            {
                title: 'Web Content',
                height: 960,
                width: 1024,
                modal:true,
                centered: true,
            }
        ).plug(
            A.Plugin.DialogIframe,
            {
                uri: url.toString(),
                iframeCssClass: 'dialog-iframe'
            }
        ).render();
    });
}
```

And image with the problem..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css file:

```
.dialog-iframe{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know about this css instruction!